# CSS stying an md-autocomplete tag

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

How can I remove shadow, change font and style AngularJS Material md-autocomplete tag?

I tried using

```
md-autocomplete style="border:none"
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .mat-autocomplete-panel{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: does this work for angularJS? I guess mat-autocomplete-panel is associated with angular

Comment: Yes it's for `Angular` not `AngularJS` sorry. Maybe look at [this](https://codepen.io/jensbodal/pen/PbqKjm)?

Comment: I wanted to enable autocomplete for one of the input tags in my form, but the style of md-autocomplete is not matching with that of other elements in the form